# VC/include/functional", line 233: error: <typeinfo> must be included before typeid is used

Tags: c++

We are porting VC8 to VC12, While compiling  target we are getting below error.
    "//Microsoft Visual Studio/VC/include/functional", line 233: error:
               must be included before typeid is used
                    return (typeid(typename _Callable::_MyTy));
                            ^

```
/Microsoft Visual Studio/VC/include/functional", line 233: error:
          no suitable user-defined conversion from "const type_info" to
          "const type_info" exists
                return (typeid(typename _Callable::_MyTy));
                       ^

/Microsoft Visual Studio/VC/include/functional", line 473: error:
          <typeinfo> must be included before typeid is used
                return (_Impl ? _Impl->_Target_type() : typeid(void));
```

Comment: Did you try adding the typeinfo include?

Comment: @RussellGreene Thanks for the response. yes typeinfo is included.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be related to the schema compiler included in Versant 8.0.2.47.3254. Seems like including  in any header file which is included in the schema results in this error.

With the hope that it will be useful for someone (or someone might post a solution for it) I'm going to document it in detail.

It can be reproduced even with two simple files:

schema.imp:

> ```
> #include "mama.hpp"
> O_CAPTURE_SCHEMA(Mama);
> ```

mama.hpp:

> ```
> #include <functional>
> class Mama{};
> ```

Trying to compile the schema will result in this error.

> > schcomp.exe schema.imp
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\eh.h",
>   line 58: error:
>             identifier "type_info" is undefined   _CRTIMP int __cdecl _is_exception_typeof(*In* const type_info &_Type, *In* struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS * _ExceptionPtr);
>                                                         ^
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\INCLUDE\functional", line 233: error:
>              must be included before typeid is used
>                   return (typeid(typename _Callable::_MyTy));
>                           ^
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\INCLUDE\functional", line 233: error:
>             no suitable user-defined conversion from "const type_info" to
>             "const type_info" exists
>                   return (typeid(typename _Callable::_MyTy));
>                          ^
>
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\INCLUDE\functional", line 473: error:
>              must be included before typeid is used
>                   return (_Impl ? _Impl->_Target_type() : typeid(void));
>                                                           ^
>
> 4 errors detected in the compilation of "schema.imp".

No solution found so far except removing the  include from the headers.